# Update default XFS quotas to all existing users?

Tags: xfs, quota, ubuntu-22.04

How can I update existing default user quotas on XFS if I already have a default value defined?

For example: I have a home directory with existing user quota defined and now I've upgraded it with the following command:

`xfs_quota -x -c "limit bsoft=2048m bhard=2304m -d" /home`

But after running the old quotas are still in place, only `root` got updated:

```
root@northshire:/home# xfs_quota -x -c "report -h"
User quota on /home (/dev/xvdb1)
                        Blocks              
User ID      Used   Soft   Hard Warn/Grace   
---------- --------------------------------- 
root          40K     2G   2.2G  00 [------]
user         1.7M     1G   1.1G  00 [------]
```

How can I delete/refresh the old quota information and apply the new one for all existing users?

Comment: Simply set all users' quotas to 0 and the default will apply on the next write. xfs uses the quota for the root user to indicate default quota. The root user never has quota applied to it.